# RExcel Runtime Error

Tags: r

Has anyone ever received a runtime error '13' type mismatch when trying to run R from within Excel using RExcel?

The install previously worked.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail? What exactly did you try to do, and what is the system you're working on? With this information it's impossible to reproduce the error to know what went wrong.

Comment: It is on Windows.  It is actually happening to my professor; I wanted to try to help her out and I can't even get the bundle to install on my machine (Windows 7).  Simply, she is trying to load in a dataset when she gets the message.  One recommendation was to stop and restart the R-server, but that didn't work.  I know it is tough when it isn't my machine, but I figure other people must have had similar issues.

Comment: I understand the purpose of this package, but I wonder if it's not just easier to do the whole analysis in R if there are so many problems with connecting the two.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel and Windows? 
Did you install all updates and service packs in Excel?

Comment: I got the same problem today. The Rcode in VBA worked until today but stopped working now...Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710443/error-with-rexcel-when-starting-up-excel/22710974?noredirect=1#22710974